# select previous date, mysql

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have a table which contains a date column, `dte`, an id column, `id`, and a value column, `val`.  Each id contains multiple dates and each date contains multiple ids: this is a panel data set.  I would like to retrieve the current date, the current value, and the value from the last available date (prior to the current date) for each id.  What is the best way to do this in mysql?  My table is not very large (2 mil records) and I would like this to work within a reasonable amount of time.

Here is a sample of the data:

```
dte, id, value
2001-01-01, 1, 10
2001-01-02, 1, 20
2001-01-03, 1, 30
2001-01-04, 1, 40
2001-01-01, 2, 100
2001-01-02, 2, 200
2001-01-03, 2, 300
2001-01-05, 2, 400
2001-01-01, 3, 1000
2001-01-02, 3, 2000
2001-01-05, 3, 3000
```

I would like to retrieve the following:

```
dte, id, value, previous_value
2001-01-01, 1, 10, NULL
2001-01-02, 1, 20, 10
2001-01-03, 1, 30, 20
2001-01-04, 1, 40, 30
2001-01-01, 2, 100, NULL
2001-01-02, 2, 200, 100
2001-01-03, 2, 300, 200
2001-01-05, 2, 400, 300
2001-01-01, 3, 1000, NULL
2001-01-02, 3, 2000, 1000
2001-01-05, 3, 3000, 2000
```

This should be done in pure SQL without the need to involve any scripting language.

Comment: Please post a sample of the data.

Answer (score 2):

Since you need only one column from the "previous" row, you could try something like this:

```
SELECT
  dte,
  id,
  value,
  (
    SELECT value
    FROM atable
    WHERE id = t.id
      AND dte < t.dte
    ORDER BY dte DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS previous_value
FROM atable t
```

If you need to pull more "previous" attributes, here's a more sophisticated approach:

```
SELECT
  t1.dte,
  t1.id,
  t1.value,
  t2.dte,
  t2.value,
  …
FROM atable t1
  LEFT JOIN atable t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.dte > t2.dte
  LEFT JOIN atable t3 ON t1.id = t3.id AND t1.dte > t3.dte AND t3.dte > t2.dte
WHERE t3.id IS NULL
```

The second approach uses a triangular self-join as well as an anti-join to self. Basically, it could be translated like this:

> Combine every row with every predecessor of its with the same `id` (the first outer join, the triangular join), then get rid of every row where the predecessor part doesn't represent the latest predecessor (the second outer join + the condition in `WHERE`, or the anti-join).

Comment: thanks so much for your answer. this is actually what i am doing currently but the performance of correlated subqueries seems to be pretty poor in mysql. any ideas about optimizing?

Comment: Would be happy to help, but this is not really my area of expertise, I'm afraid. Where straightforward solutions do not help and fine tuning is required, I very often resort to experimenting. Anyway, for me, indexes would be the first thing to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
select dte,id,value,(select value as previous_value from sample where id=1 
and dte<(select dte from sample where id=1 order by dte desc limit 1) order by
dte desc limit 1) from sample where id=1;
```

Or maybe the solution might be something similar.
This is for one id. You might have to loop the code for each such id.

Comment: I think I understood your question wrong. Thanks for posting the sample data.

Comment: i'm trying to do this in SQL, I assume the answer above is in some scripting language?